# Property of nowhere constant and continuously differentiable function.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is

1. Nowhere constant, i.e., not constant on any non-empty open set $O\subset\mathbb{R}$, and
2. Continuously differentiable, i.e., differentiable with continuous derivative.

*Proposition:* there exists a collection of mutually disjoint non-empty open intervals $(O_j)_{j\in \mathcal{J}}$ with $\overline{\cup_j O_j}=\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $j\in \mathcal{J}$ and all $x\in O_j$ it holds that $f'(x)\not = 0$.

Is there a smart way to prove this by invoking established results? If need be, it is okay to assume for simplicity that $f$ is three times differentiable.

*For example, one takes a point $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with $f'(x)\not = 0$ and use continuity to say that there exists an non-empty open interval $O_1\ni x$ such that $f'(z) \not =0$ for all $z\in O_1$. I assume that this can be iteratively done on each side with two new non-empty open intervals $O_2,O_3$ with $\sup(O_2)=\inf(O_1)$ and $\sup(O_1) = \inf(O_3)$ and so on. But this becomes a bit cumbersome to write formally in my opinion.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not smart, but still simple: the set $A = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : f'(x) = 0 \}$

- is closed by the continuity of $f'$,
- has empty interior, as otherwise $f$ would be constant on some open interval.

It is well known that every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a countable union of disjoint open intervals, so we can write

$$\mathbb{R} \setminus A = \bigcup_{j \in J} I_j$$

where each $I_j$ is a disjoint open interval and $J$ is countable.

The second bullet means precisely that $\overline{ \bigcup_{j \in J} I_j } = \mathbb{R}$. Also it is clear by definition that $f'(x) \neq 0$ on each $I_j$.

By the way the last statement implies that $f$ is strictly monotone on $I_j$ because $f'$ has the IVP.

Answer (score 1):

The lemma you need is this: the connected components of an open set U in $\mathbb{R}$ are open intervals.

Now let U := $\{ x | f'(x) \neq 0\}$

f' is C0, so U is open; and U is also the disjoint union of its connected components: those components are the $O_j$ we are looking for.

We just need to prove that U is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ to conclude: if it was not the case, there would be a non empty interval $V$ such that $\forall x \in V , f'(x)= 0 $. But then f would be constant on V.